# Game based on old phone 'Snake' Game

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm trying to remember the name of a board game based on the phone game 'snake'  This hasn't been easy to google as 'board game' and 'snake' return Snakes And Ladders.

I recall playing the game approximately 8 -10  years ago so would be at least as old as that.

Each player had a snake made up of wooden pieces.  Players gave snakes movement orders with cards to go forward, left or right.  I *think* you laid them face down in front of you for next three turns so all players would execute there first move and then lay a card for move in three turns time.

The objective I think was to collect 'apple tokens' which appeared on the board.  As you did this your snake grew by adding a wooden piece to the end of it.  I think each snake had a head piece which you moved and then just picked up the last part of the snake and moved to to the front to connect the head.

In terms of design I recall the board being a grid shape and decorated in forest/grassland green colours.

Hopefully this rings a bell with someone.

Comment: The video version of this predates phones that could play games by roundly twenty years.  Arcade games, home video games, one and two player versions.  Your board game might well be pre-iPhone and pre-Android as well.

Comment: it may well i've been,  I just put the guide line of when I played to say its not a new game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/21729/snake-lake

> The game is about a group of snakes wandering in the woods trying to eat the apples that fall down from the trees (and avoiding eating the poisonous mushrooms).

Search terms:

> snake board game apples -ladders

(The minus sign tells Google to return results without that term)

Comment: Yes,  Thats the one I was trying to remember!  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This might be [Atari's Centipede Board Game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/223763/ataris-centipede) in which one player plays the centipede trying to invade a garden, and the other plays the gnome trying to defend by killing the centipede.  There appear to be both dice and cards involved, and the images of the board match the forest/grassland color scheme.

Comment: That looks very similar but its not it.  I don't think game I'm thinking of had a brand attached.  the snake pieced were longer on mine if I recall,  more like 'ticket to ride train' size wooden pieces for the snake body.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: I didn't down vote it though for being wrong!  it seemed a completely reasonable answer based on the information I gave.